# Move replies to same folder that Outlook Rules move emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter

I have multiple rules set up for clients, each client has their own folder where all emails are directed.
When there is an internal reply to one of those emails, I'd like the reply to end up in the same folder.

Can't use domain based rules (IF *@clientdomain.com is in to/from/cc THEN move to specified folder) as some clients have multiple folders and specific people go to specific folders.

I'm looking for a method to capture internal replies (or any replies to the conversation)
Something along the lines of 'Always Move Messages in This Conversation' but automatic that matches the rules I already have configured.

Comment: Does the email move after your rule moves it? If not, then the first rule should be possible to edit to include mails from coworkers

Comment: The rules move emails from clients - The rules are set up based on client email addresses.
If a client sends me and a coworker an email, it gets moved to the client folder. If that coworker than replies all, their email sits in my inbox rather than client specific folder.

If I use the 'Always Move Message in This Conversation' - Coworker replies will be moved.
But other than that, the replies from coworkers need to be moved manually.

Comment: So it sounds like your first rule is not setup correctly and has an exception in it that you maybe want, but not mentioning and is causing this exact behavior. Can you post your rule for one client and blur out the emailadress as image, and edit it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it cannot be done by rules. In Outlook desktop client, what can we do is to enable "Shown as Conversations".

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.